# Self-Executing Anonymous Function with Revealing Module Pattern - in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, revealing-module-pattern, self-executing-function

On the basis of this js example, what would be the preferred way to do the same in ts the ts way - I have been experimenting with classes, modules and namespaces but still unsure and still not getting a match so would like to see your ideas;

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  var MyProject = MyProject = MyProject || {};
  var MyArea = MyProject.MyArea = MyProject.MyArea || {}; 

  MyArea.MyModule = (function() {
    var PublicFunction = function() { };

    var PrivateFunction = function() { };

    return {
      PublicFunction: PublicFunction
    };
  })();
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The idea behind it is creating a Self-Executing Anonymous Function, using Revealing Module Pattern and placing all my modules in a single namespace defined by myself.

Comment: You really *really* want to assign that `MyProject`, ey? :o)

Comment: Such contortions are no longer necessary. ES6/TS has native modules. Use them.

Comment: Heh - well, a little copy/paste leftover from a project where I was extending windows-object (var xx = window.xx = window.xx || {};). I think you get the point anyway ;)

Comment: @torazaburo As I wrote I wanted to do it the ts way but if I knew how I would not ask :) Will this be the way to do it then?

module Foo {
  export module Bar {
    export function publicmethod() {
      console.log(1);
    }
    function privatemethod() {
      console.log(2);
    }
  }
}

If not, can you give an example? And what about the idea of Self-Executing Anonymous Function - not needed or?